# c# The function evaluation requires all threads to run - after installing Entity Framework 6.4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

Hope this isn't to confusing, if so, please let me know.

Before I went from EF5 to EF6 , AND upgrading to Visual Studio 16.6.3, I could run debug and stop at an `IQueryable` variable created by a LINQ statement. When I get to a breakpoint after the variable, I try to hover over to see the values of this variable, and I could see them.

After the upgrades, now when I hover over the variable I get:

[image: This is initially what I get.]

This is the small message at the bottom - The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

I have seen mentions of the tools/options/debugging/ "Enable property evaluation or other implicit function calls" option. But for me, Checked or unChecked doesn't seem to show me The values when I hover over the variable and click "Results View".

However I see it being said that you can just click "Evaluate". I remember seeing that in one of my previous versions of Visual Studio, but in version 16.6.3, I can't see it.

Yesterday,I saw this and tried it and could see the results at some point, and doing this when you hover "Non-Public members > _internalQuery >  ObjectQuery > Results View".

Today I tried this again with "Enable property evaluation or other implicit function calls" (checked and unChecked), and I couldn't go through the path - "Non-Public members > _internalQuery >  ObjectQuery >  Results View", so, I couldn't see the results.

But since it worked once I (I need to find it again), am wondering if this workaround is actually the new way of getting to the Results View because of either the upgrade to Entity Framework 6 or Visual Stdio 16.6.3?

I am leaning towards the Entity Framework as the culprit?

Thanks for any advice or help

Comment: Try this work around: SO, here is the first sequence of events in order to see your results view (this evaluates your IQueryable variable):
1 – highlight IQueryable variable. 
The first time you hover, you will see 2 braided icons.
2 – click on the local braided icon. 
3 – click non public members. 
4 – click on _internalQuery.
5 – click on ObjectQuery. 
6 – click on review results.